# missing python dependencies when installing phablet-tools for ubuntu touch preview

Tags: installation, package-management, dependencies

I'm on ubuntu 13.04 and I run into similar situation and don't know how to resolve the dependencies issues. Anyone can help?

```
mk@MS7549:~$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
[sudo] password for mk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phablet-tools : Depends: python-configobj but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-launchpadlib but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-requests but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried to install those 3 python packages but they are NOT available. What do I need to do now?

```
mk@MS7549:~$ sudo apt-get install python-configobj
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-configobj is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-configobj' has no installation candidate
```

---

```
mk@MS7549:~$ sudo apt-get install python-launchpadlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-launchpadlib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-launchpadlib' has no installation candidate
```

---

```
mk@MS7549:~$ sudo apt-get install python-requests
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-requests is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-requests' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What other sources (universe, multiverse, partner) do you have enabled? Are you up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Ubuntu **13.04** 64-bit.

### ***Did you do first add the PPA?***

from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

Comment: yes. I did both sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools

and sudo apt-get update. However, when it comes to sudo apt-get install phablet-tools, I have problems.

Comment: Note that I did sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb and sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot separately and they are fine. I only have issues with phablet-tools. Any insights on why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem for 13.10.
What I did was to change the the "Download From: " server in the "Software & Update".
It was set on "Server for Sweden" (Since I am from Sweden) and
I switched to Download from "Main server" and suddenly everything started working.
So either the Swedish server was out of date or something had gone awry in my old updates that now works.

Hope it helps!

Edit: And yes I had added the ppa and made an apt-get update